# UINavigationController - Keep Navigation Bar the same when pushing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I set a `titleView` that uses a graphic on my `navigationBar`.  When I push a new `viewController` I keep that graphic in the `titleView` of the pushed controller.

I hate the sliding effect of the `navigationBar`. Is there a way to prevent the transition from affecting the `navigationBar` so that my `titleView` image doesn't give the appearance of sliding in a new version when the new view gets pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the animation state to NO when you push the new view controller that should prevent the animation.

```
[self.navigationcontroller pushVewController:newVC animated:NO];
```

EDIT:  Created custom view that sits inside of the navigation controller but you need to create your own custom images to replace functionality of navigation bar images. This however is not transitioning for me which I believe is the desired outcome.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = nil;
    UIView *staticTitle = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds];
    [staticTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [staticTitle setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:staticTitle];
    UIButton *customButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 100, 60)];
    [customButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [customButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [staticTitle addSubview:customButton];
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I DO want the view to animate in, but NOT the 'navigationBar'.

Comment: Did this method work or did you find a better solution?  This customization method is something I can see much value in knowing the best way to implement.